# Preference page do not resize when an expandable composite s expanded

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, preferences

I am creating a preference page for an eclipse plugin we developed. in the preference page there is an Expandable Composite. it is by default collapsed but when it is expanded the window will not resize and even no scrolls appear! so you have to drag the window open to see the options. I use GridLayout for my container and also the Expandable Composite but still have this problem. I even tries to manually setSize of the container and still no luck. does anyone else had the same problem and solved it?

Thanks in advance.

```
final Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.FILL);
    container.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

final ExpandableComposite collap = new ExpandableComposite(container, SWT.Collapse);
        collap.setClient(advancedOptions);
        collap.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        advancedOptions.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        advancedOptions.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
```

Comment: Note: `SWT.Collapse` is not a style flag and is not valid for an `ExpandableComposite` style.

Comment: Quite a few preference pages use ExpandableComposite but I don't think any of them resize when it is expanded. Getting scrolling to work will need something like a ScrollableComposite and use of a expand listener.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks for the response, I tried scrollableComposite as well but it does not appear and still have the same problem. I added the addExpansionListener and inside statechanged I used the Scrollable! is that the way I should use it?